# Android studio v1 - actionbar not showing

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been using the beta version until now. Now that I've upgraded to v1, any new project that I start doesn't show the actionbar in the design view. Is there a workaround? It shows up fine on the devices I'm testing it on put just doesn't show in the design mode.
The only thing different on the device compared to before is that the app icon doesn't show on the actionbar.

Solved: The issue was due to the theme.

**Won't show the icon and doesn't show the action bar in the design editor:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

**Will show the icon and action bar in the design mode**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Answer (score 3):

`Android Studio` by default creates new Application with `Appcompat-v7`. So your application theme was `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. And Material design does not support `ActionBar`. And that is the reason that you cannot see `ActionBar` as well as App icon in design view. If you want `ActionBar` like functionality then you can use `toolbar`.

By changing theme to `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` solves issue but then your app will not be created with material design. (Choice is upto you).

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

You have to make sure the android:theme line isn't saying .NoActionBar